# load kernel extension through C API?

Tags: c, macos, kernel-extension, xnu

Is it possible to load a *kernel extension* (`kext`) through a *C API* instead of using the `system()` call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you want the [KextManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IOKit/Reference/KextManager_header_reference/index.html) API. In particular, `KextManagerLoadKextWithIdentifier()` is probably the function you'll want to use to load an installed kext, versus `KextManagerLoadKextWithURL()` if you want to load a kext that is not in /System/Library/Extensions or /Library/Extensions but e.g. in an .app bundle.

Answer (score 0):

```
CFStringRef km_path = CFStringCreateWithCString(kCFAllocatorDefault, "/Library/Extensions/KauthORama.kext",
                                                    kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
CFURLRef km_url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(kCFAllocatorDefault, km_path,
                                           kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, true);
OSReturn status  = KextManagerLoadKextWithURL(km_url, NULL);
if (status == kOSReturnSuccess){
        syslog(LOG_NOTICE, "Loaded!");
    }else{
        syslog(LOG_NOTICE, "Lodaed error: %d", errno);
    }
```